# How the NAS message transmitted in N1/N2 interface in 5G Network

Tags: telecommunication

I am planning to design a simulator which mimics complete UE attachments and registration in 5G core network. Since N1 is a logical interface, how the NAS message is transmitted from the UE to RAN to AMF (At its core transfer protocol SCTP is used between RAN and AMF)? Any sample packet capture would also help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, SCTP protocol is used between AMF and gNB (RAN) just like in lte.

There is RRC protocol between UE and gNB.I do not have much knowledge in this area. But for registration this part is not important, and I think you can just send NAS as raw package to gNB.

After that, gNB put NAS-5G message (registration request in your case) from UE, to NGAP (N2) transport message, and sends it via SCTP.